# How does InstallAllUsers work

Tags: windows-installer

I am creating a .Net windows Client application with its corresponding MSI setup program.

How does the option InstallAllUsers (Install for "everyone" or "just me") option work technically:

So if the user chose to install using the "just me" option, does that mean that the binaries are only accessible by that user? And how is that done? And is it the setup program that performs those restrictions, or should I as developer do something in the MSI to implement those restrictions?

Thanks
Jihad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is framed in terms of Visual Studio setup projects, which hide all of the underlying property manipulation that goes on. VS setup projects do not use MSIINSTALLPERUSER, only ALLUSERS. It's further complicated because a per machine Everyone install sets ALLUSERS to 2, which does not even enforce a per machine install because it depends on the installing user's privileges. Generally speaking when a privileged user installs an Everyone install it will do as you'd expect. However a non-privileged user will get an install with some redirection because of the way the MSI is built.

A per user "Just me" install will install the product for only that user. If you logged on with a different account you wouldn't see it in Programs&Features. Shortcuts to apps wouldn't be visible because they would be only in the installing user's profile.  The files and registry items would be accessible to elevated administrators (because all files are) but in general other users files and registry entries will not be available to other limited users.

If your requirement is to install a product that is available to all users of the system, and which installs files to places like ProgramFiles and CommonFiles folders, or writes to HKLM registry entries then you need an Everyone install that requires the installing user to be privileged.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer depends on the version of Windows you are targeting and which mechanism the installer leverages. The older and less powerful mechanism leverages solely the [ALLUSERS property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559) and doesn't work very well in practice as the author has to manually redirect resources that would otherwise be installed to per-machine locations. The newer mechanism requires Windows 7 or later uses the [MSIINSTALLPERUSER property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007) to request automatic redirection of installed resources to per-user locations. See [Single Package Authoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068) for details.

With that in mind, the short answers to your later questions for a "just me" installation are:

- The application's files are installed to folders writable by the user, and typically visable only to that user.
- Registration goes to HKCU instead of HKLM.
- The application may have to take both potential locations into account. If it is well-written, this should not take any extra effort, but be sure to test your app thoroughly in both installed configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So that means that if there are no registry entries for that MSI, and if no writing to files is done in the application, the installation will actually work for all users who have read access to the application files folder (typically Program Files) even if the installation was performed with the "Just Me" option chosen

Comment: ... moreover: In the project file that creates the MSI, I can specify which registry keys to create. And if I add registry keys to both HKLM and HKCU then it creates both registry entries, and it does not depend on whether I have chosen "All users" or "Just me"